# How to provide excerpt for a new tag ?

Tags: support, tags, tag-excerpt

I recently added a new `tag` in SO which is waiting for review. Now I see no buttons/links which lead to provide an excerpt for it. I'm asking for a simple walk through.

Or I've to wait for it's approval ? If so, how the reviewers will know why I created it ?

Comment: By exceprt, you mean the "Edit Summary" thing?

Comment: I accepted ur answer. But it still doesn't explain `how the reviewers will know why I created it` thing !

Comment: Generally tag wikis are fairly obvious at first glance, and don't need context.  The "Nothing to something" change [is fairly obvious](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/2286).  What would you end up putting there?  "Created tag wiki"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm assuming you mean the "Edit Summary" field.

There is no way to propose an edit summary when you initially create the post, just as I cannot provide an edit summary when I first provide an answer.  There also usually is no need to.

However, you *can* save your edit and then click edit again and supply the description then, where you would normally find it.  Doing that will still be part of your original edit.

I suspect that they do not give this option simply because there shouldn't be a need to provide it.

If you are referring to the actual tag wiki excerpt, it's right there:

> [image: Excerpt is circled.]